# you have no privileges to view this object or it does not exist

Tags: vsphere, vcenter

In vCenter 6.5 vSphere web client, if I logon as any user other than administrator@vsphere.local, I can't get to a few areas like Administration > Single sign on > Configuration.
I swear I did something to get my other user accounts access before, but if it's not just to give administrator access to 'global access', then I can't remember. vCenter died recently and I had to recreate it.
I'm trying to give otherUser@vsphere.local and an Active Directory group full access to do everything that administrator@vsphere.local can do.
Anyone know how to do this?
Note: I have the vCenter Server **Appliance**.

Comment: Perhaps updating the registry might help https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2125229

Answer (score 3):

There's separate roles and permissions for vCenter and Appliance configurations (such as SSO). Make sure you're properly setting the permissions for those users/groups there as well.

Example of the SSO permissions: [link](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.5/com.vmware.psc.doc/GUID-87DA2F34-DCC9-4DAB-8900-1BA35837D07E.html)